# Skitch like plugin for Phonegap

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova, draw

I am trying to find a Skitch like plugin for Phonegap. I currently have the ability to bring up the camera from my phonegap app and snap a picture, but I want the ability to edit the photo to add a freehand drawing/text/arrows, just like skitch has or any of the applications in the app store. Any help is appreciated. Heres a photo of what Skitch looks like,

[image]
[image]